# Spring Boot FreeMarker: How to use custom template on the fly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

I want to use freemarker in my spring boot app. The template will be loaded from db or file whatever, but how can I use this with the SpringTemplateLoader? As I understood there is always the expectation that the file is somewhere on the disk, but in my case it can be loaded from different sources.

Here is my test case

```
    File testPdf = getResourceFile("template/test.ftl");
    assertThat(testPdf.exists()).isTrue();
    Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
    model.put("firstName", "Dave");
    model.put("lastName", "Grohl");

    String replacedString = FreeMarkerUtil.getContentFromTemplate(Files.readAllBytes(testPdf.toPath()) , model);
    assertThat(replacedString).isEqualTo(expectedReplacedString);
```

I am trying to use the SpringTemplateLoader which needs a Resourceloader and a templateLoaderPath, but I have no path, I want that the template will be loaded from the byte[]

```
public static String getContentFromTemplate(byte[] template, Map<String, String> model){
    ByteArrayResource templateResource = new ByteArrayResource(template);
    SpringTemplateLoader loader = new SpringTemplateLoader(templateResource, )
    
    
}
```

Or do I need to store the ftl on disk and configure this path in the Configuration of FreeMarker?

Comment: Don't use the `SpringTemplateLoader` then.. Write your own `TemplateLoader` instance that retrieves them from the database. Then extend the `FreemarkerConfigurer` (override the `postProcessTemplateLoaders` method) and add this specialized template loader to the list of loaders.

Comment: Thx, I will try this. Maybe you have example or something alike in the web?

Comment: You would need a `TemplateLoader` for all the different locations you support (file is supported out-of-the-box so that shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: What if I store the file in the configured destination and then use the default behaviour of the SpringTemplateLoader? Then it should also work?

Comment: Yes as that resolves files.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't assume that the file is coming from a file. Where the templates are loaded from depends on the `TemplateLoader` implementation. So you may want to configure FreeMarker to use your own implementation.

Note that a template can also be created directly from a `String`, with the `Template` constructor. In some applications that's the simplest solution. The drawback of that is that such templates can't be referred from other templates by name (like via `#import` or `#include`). Also for such `Template` objects FreeMarker doesn't do the caching for you, obviously.